# How to dynamically assign Puppeteer viewport size from current screen resolution?

Tags: puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer to automate some page actions in an already open, fully-visible browser (non-headless). Currently, I manually set the viewport like this:

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setViewport({width: W, height: H});
```

I have to manually set `W` and `H` based on both the actual screen resolution, and on the system-wide scaling factor. This makes the script very brittle and non-portable.

I would like to have the new page always open with the largest possible visible viewport, without having to manually specify what that is. I tried some of the other solutions suggested on SO and elsewhere, such as setting the viewport to `null`, but I have not yet stumbled upon a working solution for my specific use case. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: am I understanding correctly that: your problem is: (1) you set `page.setViewPort()` and it will be good, (2) but when you have a new tab opened (let's call it `page2`) then it will have the usual, smaller viewport again, so you need to set `page2.setViewPort()` again, etc.? the `defaultViewport: null` maximizes your chromium window, but the opened pages will still remain in a reduced viewport, am I right?

Comment: Hi, no, my problem is that I don't want to be forced to use `page.setViewport`, I want `browser.newPage()` to always open pages that take up the maximum available screen space.

Comment: I see (actually that's the same what I wrote :) )

Comment: suggested title revision for clarification: **How to dynamically assign Puppeteer viewport size from current screen resolution ?**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the `W` and `H` persistently across a launched browser you need to set [`defaultViewport: null`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-puppeteerlaunchoptions) together with [`--window-size=${W},${H}`](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#window-size) launch arg. It sets the window size and viewport on `browser`-level, not on `page`-level (which changes with each new tab).

Like this, all the newly opened tabs will share the same window size and viewport.

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    defaultViewport: null,
    args: [`--window-size=${W},${H}`]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can retrieve the screen resolution from system specifications you would be able to correctly set the viewport size from it.

Though you will probably not be able to get this information directly from javascript.

If you can get this information **from a PowerShell script** (*see edit*), you could try the following to execute that script from javascript and retrieve this information in your program in order to set your viewport dimensions.

```js
const {spawn} = require("child_process");

async function getSomeDataFromAPowerShellScript() {
    const child = spawn("powershell.exe", ["./PATH/MyPowerShellScript.ps1"]); // spawn a powershell terminal as a child process of main program and run the provided script in it 
    
    return await new Promise(resolve => {
        child.stdout.on("data", (data) => { // trigger when data is send into the child terminal
            console.log(data);
            resolve(data);
        };
    });

}
```

A call to `getSomeDataFromAPowerShellScript()` will **return the first outputed data** in the **powershell terminal** as a `string`.

If you want to **retrieve more informations** than just the first output in the powershell terminal you can use this instead:

```js
async function getSomeDataFromAPowerShellScript() {
    const child = spawn("powershell.exe", ["./PATH/MyPowerShellScript.ps1"]); // spawn a powershell terminal as a child process of main program and run the provided script in it
    let result = []; 

    return await new Promise(resolve => {
        child.stdout.on("data", (data) => { // trigger when data is send into the child terminal
            console.log(data);
            result.push(data);
        };

        child.on("exit", () => { // trigger when the child process exit after execution
            resolve(result);
        });
    });

}
```

**Edit:** 
You could use this powershell script from Ben N answer here [How to get the current screen resolution on windows via command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/1436909/how-to-get-the-current-screen-resolution-on-windows-via-command-line) to get the current resolution of your primary screen:

*PowerShell-script.ps1*

```rb
Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class PInvoke {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")] public static extern int GetDeviceCaps(IntPtr hdc, int nIndex);
}
"@
$hdc = [PInvoke]::GetDC([IntPtr]::Zero)
[PInvoke]::GetDeviceCaps($hdc, 118) # width
[PInvoke]::GetDeviceCaps($hdc, 117) # height
```

> *original explanation* 
> It outputs two lines: first the horizontal resolution, then the
> vertical resolution.
>
> To run it, save it to a file (e.g. screenres.ps1) and launch it with
> PowerShell:
>
> `powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass .\screenres.ps1`

Using this answer in combination of theDavidBarton answer should achieve what you're asking for.